# I can not get the jar file by maven

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, netbeans-plugins, jxta

I am treying to download the JXTA 2.7 by maven in Netbeans but i do not manage to to that. Do you have any idea why? I got the fellowing panel loading error;

```
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Error resolving project artifact: Could not transfer artifact com.kenai.jxse:jxse:pom:2.7 from/to repository.jboss.org (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2): Access denied to: http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/com/kenai/jxse/jxse/2.7/jxse-2.7.pom, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. for project com.kenai.jxse:jxse:jar:2.7
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:251)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:258)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.repository.ui.ArtifactMultiViewFactory.readMavenProject(ArtifactMultiViewFactory.java:237)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.repository.ui.ArtifactMultiViewFactory.access$000(ArtifactMultiViewFactory.java:103)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.repository.ui.ArtifactMultiViewFactory$1.run(ArtifactMultiViewFactory.java:166)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1411)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:1991)
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact com.kenai.jxse:jxse:pom:2.7 from/to repository.jboss.org (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2): Access denied to: http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/com/kenai/jxse/jxse/2.7/jxse-2.7.pom, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:285)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.kenai.jxse:jxse:pom:2.7 from/to repository.jboss.org (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2): Access denied to: http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/com/kenai/jxse/jxse/2.7/jxse-2.7.pom, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:951)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:941)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:669)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Access denied to: http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/com/kenai/jxse/jxse/2.7/jxse-2.7.pom, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:835)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:601)
... 4 more
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the repository (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/com/kenai/jxse/jxse/2.7/jxse-2.7.pom) that you are using is deprecated and is disabled.

See [this](https://community.jboss.org/message/625343?_sscc=t) and [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/539666/tools/Maven-JBoss-Repository-Error).
There is some more information in this jira issue: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBBUILD-682

Comment: @Alex : did that problem go away ? u should have tried using some other repository which is currently active

Comment: No I did not solve that. I have not used maven before. How can I change the repository in Netbeans?

Comment: see these workarounds:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBBUILD-682?focusedCommentId=12646699&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-12646699         https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBBUILD-682?focusedCommentId=12646852&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-12646852         https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBBUILD-682?focusedCommentId=12647024&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-12647024